# Mocking a Java Enum in a unit test?

Tags: java, exception, enums, switch-statement

I have the following **Factory class**:

```
public class EmployeeFactory {

    public static Employee createEmployee(Employee employee) {

        switch (employee) {
            case DOCTOR:
                return new Doctor();
            case NURSE:
                return new Nurse();
        }

       throw new EmployeeException("Invalid Employee!");
    }

}
```

**Enum class:**

```
public enum Employee {

    DOCTOR("Doctor"),
    NURSE("Nurse");

    private final String description;

    Employee(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }
}
```

I want to create a mock enum e.g. `TEACHER` that is an invalid input to my `factory` method to assert that the `exception` is thrown.

How can I do so?

**Current test:**

```
 @Test
    void shouldThrowException(){

        assertThrows(EmployeeException.class,
                () -> {
                    // arrange
                    //todo - how to?
                    Employee invalidEmployee = mock(Employee.class);
                    when(invalidEmployee.getDescription()).thenReturn("Teacher");

                    // act
                    EmployeeFactory.createEmployee(invalidEmployee);
                });
    }
```

Comment: I don't think you can. Maybe somebody can prove me wrong.

Comment: Thanks @knittl , how would you suggest testing in this case? I am not limited to mockito / junit but prefer to use them. I have added my current test for reference

Comment: What's wrong with your current test?

Comment: I don't understand how you can `new` your enum. `Employee` is an enum, so it cannot be `new`ed, yet in your method you return an `Employee` which you construct with `new`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `mockStatic` and mock the new employee like this:

```
   try (MockedStatic<Employee> employeeEnumMock = mockStatic(Employee.class)) {
        Employee TEACHER = mock(Employee.class);
        when(TEACHER.ordinal()).thenReturn(2);

        employeeEnumMock.when(Employee::values).thenReturn(new Employee[]{Employee.DOCTOR, Employee.NURSE, TEACHER});
        // call createEmployee with your teacher enum
        EmployeeFactory.createEmployee(TEACHER);
    }
```